# What does "a culture of expectations" mean here?

Tags: meaning

I was reading [this](http://www.humansofnewyork.com/post/82390781702/i-teach-fourth-grade-in-harlem-whats-your).

> Many of them just don’t have a culture of expectation at home,...
>
> Hard to do without a culture of expectation.

I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An environment in which there is an expectation for hard work and good grades.  The premise is that children who are entirely self-motivated are rare.  They are helped by receiving outside encouragement by an expectation that they will perform and achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It's a euphemism. "The culture of expectations" is code for middle class. Not wishing to get bogged down in an argument that could veer in any number of directions, I will just say, succinctly, that, as a rule, The Middle Classes have expectations, while the lower classes have few or none. In a working class environment the attitude is more likely to be: "if it was good enough for me, it's good enough for you" i.e. no change. In a Middle Class environment there will be expectations on a child to perform as well as it is able. Ths is not a universal truth, it is a general truth, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score -1):

it is simply what the culture expects from you 
what is thought to be right by that culture 
such 
when in a car accident not driving off
kids respecting  adults
Adults following the law